# How to access redis logs on AWS ElastiCache

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

We have been facing latency issues with our redis lately.

We are trying to debug what's going on, I came across [this](https://tech.trivago.com/2017/01/25/learn-redis-the-hard-way-in-production/) post and it mentioned going over the redis logs to investigate how often the db is saved in the background (ie using [bgsave](https://redis.io/commands/bgsave))

I did some research on [how to access the redis logs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337107/how-to-access-redis-log-file) but couldn't find anything on how to find it on AWS ElastiCache. I also tried running the `monitor` command from the redis cli but it's not giving me information about stuff like backing up the database etc.

How can I access such logs?

Comment: You can check AWS Console -> ElastiCache Dashboard -> Events. The backup events can be found there.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, there is no way to access to the Redis server-side logs ('yet').

src: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=219210

Answer (score 2):

This feature is available starting with version 6 Redis.

You can now publish logs from your Amazon ElastiCache for Redis clusters to CloudWatch and Kinesis Data Firehose, by enabling slow logs in ElastiCache Console.

You can read [more details here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/amazon-elasticache-now-supports-publishing-redis-logs-to-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-and-kinesis-data-firehose/)

Comment: More details related to the Log Delivery feature can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Log_Delivery.html